# Error when installing wireless display driver for Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7

I installed windows 7 ultimate 64-bit on a lenovo b590. After that I wanted to install a wireless display driver windows 7 64-bit for lenovo b590. When I double click it to start the installation of the driver a dialog box appeared with this error message:

`The version of this file is not compatible with the version of windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86(32-bit) or x64(64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.`

so I couldn't install it. Does anybody know what is causing this, how to solve the issue or is something that can be solved? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are trying to install a driver for your wireless display that is X86 (32-bit) while your operation system is a X64 bit. you need to install the x64 bit version of your driver from [here](http://support.lenovo.com/en/downloads/ds028626).

Comment: This version which you mentioned I tried to install and didn't work. I know that if I have an operating system X64 I have to look for a driver for a X64 version

Comment: Be more descriptive then it didn't work.

Comment: The driver linked to only supports Windows 7 the installer will install the appropriate driver